# instantiate and setting arrays in another array

Tags: java, arrays

i possess city,country and world classes, country and world classes are arrays since obviously i would need to add several different countries and cities in them, and i would like to add countries into the world that i had instantiated, and cities into the countries that i created, but im not sure what java code im suppose to use to do this, heres what i tried to code and it failed to run:

```
private static void AddCountriesToWorld(World[] aWorld){

        System.out.println("Entering the countries in your world");
Country[] aCountry = new Country[9];
    aWorld[0]=aCountry.setName("Usa");
    aWorld[1]=aCountry.setName("Europe");
    aWorld[2]=aCountry.setName("Russia");

    }
```

.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    World[] aWorld = new World[15];
    AddCountriesToWorld(aWorld);
       }
```

Any insight on this would be appreciated! thanks!

[edit: the code was not even correct, i wasnt able to run the program at all, problem was i don't know what the code to do the function i describe so i didnt start.]

Comment: What failed? StackTrace? you never set any elements in aWorld to be anything.

Comment: Did the assignment tell you to use arrays for this? Personally, I'd just make City, Country and World types.

Answer (score 4):

You've instantiated the array correctly, but you've never set `aWorld[0]` to anything.

In addition, `aCountry` is an array of `Country`, but you are attempting to call methods on it as if it was an instance of `Country`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you create generics Object something like this ArrayList and using methods of ArrayList class, like add(obj) or addAll(obj) an so on. I hope help you.

Comment: sorry i cant use arraylist because i havent learnt that yet, right now im only at arrays

Answer (score 0):

I think you need some practice on Arrays in Java,you can [learn here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html).

to transfer country list from Country array to world array,you need to code like below.

```
public void addCountries(Contry[] contry){
        World[] worlds=new World[contry.length];
        World world=null;
        for (int i=0;i<contry.length;i++) {
            world=new World();
            world.setCountry(contry[i].getCountry());
            worlds[i]=world;
        }

    }
```

Rest of code you try to write as it is homework,I am leaving that part